# Can't build a relationship Many-To-Many

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

There are two entities: InventoryList and Parameter.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "parameters")
public class ParameterEntity extends Parameter {

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parameters")
private Set<UUID> inventoryLists;


}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
name = "lists"
public class InventoryListEntity extends InventoryList {

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(
    name = "list_parameters",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "il_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parameter_id")
)
private Set<UUID> parameters;

}
```

There is the following issue

```
 Many To Many attribute value type should not be UUID
```

But I've got the task to make so for performance reasons.

What solutions are there in this case ???

Answer (score 0):

1. An item in the collection in the [@ManyToMany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many) association can be only other entity. So, in this case you can have only something like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "parameters")
public class ParameterEntity extends Parameter {

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parameters")
   private Set<InventoryListEntity> inventoryLists;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "lists")
public class InventoryListEntity extends InventoryList {

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinTable(
      name = "list_parameters",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "il_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parameter_id")
  )
  private Set<ParameterEntity> parameters;

}
```

2. If you want to use value or embeddable type in the collection you should use the [@ElementCollection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-value) annotation. But you should remember that *the lifecycle of the value-type collection is entirely controlled by its owning entity*. And as a result, you can not have bidirectional relationship in this case.